# Efficiently iterate over bed and subset pyranges objects

Tags: python, bed, pyranges

I am using [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) and I have two datasets that I want to compare in several genome-wide intervals based on a bed file.

For every interval in the bed file, I want to get all overlapping positions from the two datasets and sum two columns. That gives me 4 numbers for a fisher exact test, but that's not the most important part.

My current [code](https://github.com/wdecoster/methplotlib/blob/master/scripts/allele_specific_modification.py) looks like below, and just iterates over the itertuples() of the bed file as pandas dataframe, and uses that to slice the pyranges object:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyranges as pr
from pyranges import PyRanges
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact
import numpy as np


def main():
    colnames = ["Chromosome", "Start", "End", "num_motifs", "calls", "methylated", "freq", "seq"]
    h1 = PyRanges(pd.read_csv("dataset1.tsv.gz", sep="\t", names=colnames, header=0))
    h2 = PyRanges(pd.read_csv("dataset2.tsv.gz", sep="\t", names=colnames, header=0))
    for chr, begin, end in pr.read_bed("chr21.bed.gz").merge().as_df().itertuples(index=False, name=None):
        odr, pv = fisher_exact([meth_counts(h1[chr, begin:end]),
                                meth_counts(h2[chr, begin:end])])


def meth_counts(interval):
    if not interval.empty:
        all, methylated = interval.as_df()[['calls', "methylated"]].sum()
        return [all - methylated, methylated]
    else:
        return [0, 0]
```

This code works well, but I'm not sure if I use the "full power" of what pyranges could offer me for iterating and subsetting. I uploaded some example data on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1N5SIcmeFFGaQgrQSuinOyrmCaLw1f-cX?usp=sharing) (250GB).

Comment: Note that `gr[chr, begin:end]` will create a new NCLS to do lookups for every single iteration. This is sloooow. It is better to use functions like overlap, intersect, join etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyranges as pr
from pyranges import PyRanges
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact
import numpy as np

# ! zcat dataset1.tsv.gz | head -2
# chromosome    start   end num_motifs_in_group called_sites    called_sites_methylated methylated_frequency    group_sequence
# chr21 5010053 5010053 1   3   0   0.000   CACCACGTCCA

# avoid using more columns than we need, especially seq which contains object
# is heavy to lug around
colnames = ["Chromosome", "Start", "End", "calls", "methylated"]
usecols = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]

h1 = PyRanges(pd.read_csv("dataset1.tsv.gz", sep="\t", names=colnames, header=0, usecols=usecols))
h2 = PyRanges(pd.read_csv("dataset2.tsv.gz", sep="\t", names=colnames, header=0, usecols=usecols))

regions = pr.read_bed("chr21.bed.gz")
regions = regions[~regions.Chromosome.str.contains("_")].merge()

regions.ID = list(range(len(regions)))

regions
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | ID        |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (int64)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
# | chr21        | 5065660   | 5065810   | 0         |
# | chr21        | 5068140   | 5068290   | 1         |
# | chr21        | 5128400   | 5128550   | 2         |
# | chr21        | 5154780   | 5154930   | 3         |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...       |
# | chr21        | 46637040  | 46637190  | 2377      |
# | chr21        | 46638480  | 46638630  | 2378      |
# | chr21        | 46639820  | 46639970  | 2379      |
# | chr21        | 46692680  | 46692830  | 2380      |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 2,381 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.

h1
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | calls     | methylated   |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (int64)   | (int64)      |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr21        | 5010053   | 5010053   | 3         | 0            |
# | chr21        | 5010215   | 5010215   | 5         | 1            |
# | chr21        | 5010331   | 5010335   | 6         | 0            |
# | chr21        | 5010525   | 5010525   | 2         | 2            |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...       | ...          |
# | chr21        | 46699713  | 46699718  | 274       | 254          |
# | chr21        | 46699739  | 46699739  | 133       | 113          |
# | chr21        | 46699756  | 46699756  | 37        | 32           |
# | chr21        | 46699770  | 46699773  | 156       | 130          |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 331,373 rows and 5 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

Get total number of methylated per region:

```
def count_total_and_methylated(df):
    """For each region in bed, get sum of calls and methylated"""

    grpby = df.groupby("ID")
    total = grpby.calls.sum()
    methylated = grpby.methylated.sum()

    chromosome = df.Chromosome.iloc[0]
    start = grpby.Start.first()
    end = grpby.End.first()
    region_id = grpby.ID.first()

    return pd.DataFrame({"Chromosome": chromosome, "Start": start, "End": end, "ID": region_id,
                         "calls": total, "methylated": methylated})

rh1 = regions.join(h1).drop(like="_b").apply(count_total_and_methylated)
rh2 = regions.join(h2).drop(like="_b").apply(count_total_and_methylated)

rh1.File = 1
rh2.File = 2

def add_missing(df, df2):

    """Since join is inner rh1 and rh2 might not have the exact same intervals. Fix this."""

    missing_in_first = np.setdiff1d(df2.ID, df.ID)
    first_missing = df2[df2.ID.isin(missing_in_first)].copy()

    f = df.File.head().iloc[0]

    first_missing.loc[:, "File"] = f
    first_missing.loc[:, "calls"] = 0
    first_missing.loc[:, "methylated"] = 0

    return pd.concat([df, first_missing])

rh1 = rh1.apply_pair(rh2, add_missing)
rh2 = rh2.apply_pair(rh1, add_missing)


j = rh1.join(rh2, suffix=2).drop(like="File*|ID*|(Start|End)2")
j
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | calls     | methylated   | calls2    | methylated2   |
# | (object)     | (int32)   | (int32)   | (int64)   | (int64)      | (int64)   | (int64)       |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------|
# | chr21        | 5065660   | 5065810   | 188       | 8            | 70        | 0             |
# | chr21        | 5068140   | 5068290   | 168       | 166          | 74        | 72            |
# | chr21        | 5128400   | 5128550   | 901       | 14           | 143       | 1             |
# | chr21        | 5154780   | 5154930   | 653       | 0            | 593       | 0             |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...       | ...          | ...       | ...           |
# | chr21        | 46637040  | 46637190  | 66        | 63           | 69        | 62            |
# | chr21        | 46638480  | 46638630  | 28        | 0            | 30        | 3             |
# | chr21        | 46639820  | 46639970  | 22        | 0            | 18        | 14            |
# | chr21        | 46692680  | 46692830  | 71        | 25           | 57        | 23            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 1,922 rows and 7 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

Compute fisher exact using [fisher](https://github.com/brentp/fishers_exact_test) instead of scipy:

```
def fe(df):
    from fisher import pvalue_npy

    cols = "calls methylated calls2 methylated2".split()
    df[cols] = df[cols].astype(np.uint)
    _, _, two_sided = pvalue_npy(df.calls.values, df.methylated.values, df.calls2.values, df.methylated2.values)

    t1, t2, m1, m2 = df.calls, df.calls2, df.methylated, df.methylated2

    _or =   (t1 * m2) / (t2 * m1)

    df.insert(df.shape[1], "PValue", two_sided)
    df.insert(df.shape[1], "OR", _or)

    return df

result = j.apply(fe, nb_cpu=1)
result.drop(like="methylated*|calls*")
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+--------------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | PValue                 | OR                 |
# | (object)     | (int32)   | (int32)   | (float64)              | (float64)          |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+--------------------|
# | chr21        | 5065660   | 5065810   | 0.1152954430992567     | 0.0                |
# | chr21        | 5068140   | 5068290   | 0.9999999999995065     | 0.9846955389124064 |
# | chr21        | 5128400   | 5128550   | 0.7075919513120225     | 0.4500499500499501 |
# | chr21        | 5154780   | 5154930   | 1.0                    | nan                |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...                    | ...                |
# | chr21        | 46638480  | 46638630  | 0.24262295081967644    | inf                |
# | chr21        | 46639820  | 46639970  | 0.00024909594620266284 | inf                |
# | chr21        | 46692680  | 46692830  | 0.7354565511951735     | 1.1459649122807019 |
# | chr21        | 36784100  | 36784250  | 1.0                    | nan                |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+--------------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 1,932 rows and 5 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It seems like a decent solution but I need some more time to test it, as I'm focussing on getting a grant written these days...

Comment: Yeah, I'm writing a PR now. But with better code than here :)

Comment: I've tested that it gives the same results as your code. And it is super fast. Just wait for my PR plz

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to use Python and can't use `subprocess`, here's a quick CLI one-liner which sums signal from sorted BED5 files, over the genomic space where they overlap:

```
$ bedmap --echo --sum --delim '\t' <(bedops --merge A.bed B.bed ... N.bed) <(bedops --everything A.bed B.bed ... N.bed) > answer.bed
```

(Requires `bash` for process substitutions.)